# How to make each post open on new page in Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I need to make a front page with the flow of posts (which is the default on the platform) but each post should open on a new page with more detailed info and pictures. Something similar to WordPress - an index page and single pages.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is "Permalink Page". You can find more info on this in [tumblr's custom theme documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#basic_variables). The basics is you use `{block:PermalinkPage}{/block:PermalinkPage}` to wrap the things you only want showing in the permalink page.

To access the permalink page of the post you include the following in each post block:

```html
<a href="{Permalink}" target="_blank">more info</a>
```

It is commonplace to make the note count lead to the permalink page. The `target='_blank'` property makes the page open in a new tab.